# "Column 'Valor' no found." ao buscar saldo em query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou construindo um simulador de caixa eletrônico, com as funcionalidades de Depositar, Sacar e Extrato estão funcionais. Porém, não estou conseguindo buscar o saldo.

Tenho o método `emitirSaldo()` que deve receber o valor calculado pela query. Segue o código:

```
public Extrato emitirSaldo(Extrato mod) {

    conex.conecta();
    conex.executeSQL

    ("SELECT (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM extrato where Transacao = 'Deposito') "
        + "- (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM extrato where Transacao = 'Saque')");

    try {

        conex.resultset.first();
        mod.setSaldo(conex.resultset.getString("Valor"));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saldo recebido.");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao apresentar o saldo./nErro: " + ex);
    }

    conex.desconecta();

    return mod;

}
```

Esse método é chamado dentro do botão visualizar:

```
private void btnVisualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    model = control.emitirSaldo(model);

    lblSaldo.setText(model.getSaldo());


}
```

Quando executo o programa, esta sendo apresentado o erro:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Column 'Valor' no found."

Porém no banco de dados existe a coluna Valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso realizar o cálculo do saldo e apresenta-lo no FormSaldo, ao clicar no botão Visualizar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que sua query não vai retornar uma coluna chamada "valor". Substitua a linha:

```
mod.setSaldo(conex.resultset.getString("Valor"));
```

por

```
mod.setSaldo(conex.resultset.getString(1));
```

pois sua query irá retornar uma coluna com o resultado e essa coluna não tem nome. Esse "1" representa o índice dela.

Comment: Alternativamente é possível dar um *alias* para o resultado: `"SELECT ((SELECT SUM(valor) FROM extrato where Transacao = 'Deposito') - (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM extrato where Transacao = 'Saque')) AS resultado"` e `conex.resultset.getString("resultado");`